# MVC 5 DateTime serialization strange behavior

Tags: date, datetime, model-view-controller, serialization

I already know they are plenty of subject around that(serialization w/ timezone, ...) and I am not here to find a way to manage serialization, I actually handle that with no problem.

I just noticed something but i have no clue what going on under the wood. If you have some specs I will be happy to read them.

Here we go :
I have a c# DateTime "01/01/1950 00:00:00" (Kind is unspecified) send to JS with "/Date(-631155600000)/". In Chrome Console, if  I do `new Date(-631155600000)` I get

> Sun Jan 01 1950 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)

All seems fine, lets move on.

Now, I have a c# DateTime "01/01/1901 00:00:00" (Kind still unspecified) send to JS with "/Date(-2177456400000)/". In Chrome Console, if  I do `new Date(-2177456400000)` I get

> Mon Dec 31 1900 23:09:21 GMT+0009 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)

As you can see I don't return to the same Date. I supected some wrong TimeZone being automatically deduced but it would have been in order of magnitude of "hour". Here, minutes and seconds are messed up. Futhermore GMT+XXXX are not the same.

Any idea?
MVC that generate worng ticks if Date is Old?
Chrome Browser using another algorithm within Date constructor?
...something else?